# Prove that $f(x)=e^x+x^5$ is invertible.

Tags: calculus

How would you prove that $f(x)=e^x+x^5$ is invertible?

To prove a function is invertible it has to be bijective, so I already have the injectivity.

Here's my approach:
My argument it's that the function is strictly increasing, because the derivative is positive for all $x$, so it implies that is one-one.

The thing is that I can't prove that the function is onto; it's obvious that the "classic" approach doesn't work; what do you suggest?

Comment: What happens at $\pm \infty$?

Comment: @lulu the function goes to $\pm \infty$ respectively

Comment: Ok...can you see how that implies that it is onto?

Comment: It sounds like intermidate value theorem, so there exists a $c$ s.t. $f(c)=0$ But idk how it works to prove the onto condition

Comment: Yes.  Though not just $0$.  Any value $a\in \mathbb R$ lies between $\pm \infty$ so the intermediate value theorem (and the continuity of the function) tells us that we can solve $f(c)=a$.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem: if $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, and if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is surjective.

Proof: consider some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $N$ such that for all $x < N$, $f(x) < k$. Then $f(N - 1) < k$. And take some $M$ such that for all $x > M$, $f(x) > k$. Then $f(M + 1) > k$. Then by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $c$ between $N - 1$ and $M + 1$ such that $f(c) = k$.

As suggested in the comments, this theorem is exactly what we need here.